# How to connect a button and collectionview in tvos application?

Tags: xamarin, button, uicollectionview, tvos

I am trying to connect a `Button` and `Collectionview` in my tvos application (Xamarin - Visual Studio Mac). I need to show the `collectionview` when tap the button.

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/tvos/user-interface/collection-views?tabs=macos) blog for the implementation of `collectionview`  in my project. The 6th step on this blog tells how to connect the `Button` and `collectionview` , **Control-drag from the Button to the Collection View Controller and select Push from the popup:**

**Screenshot**

[image]

I tried a lot by dragging the `Button` to `Collectionview`, but there is no popup and they are not getting connected. I am a beginner on tv os application development. So anybody please explain this mechanism? If provide a gif file, it will be easy.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Focus on the button and click the **Control** on the keyboard at same time .
2. Move the mouse from the button to the **CollectionViewControl** .
3. Now the popup will display.

[image]